# How to filter for ManyToManyField within a list?

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-1.5

I would like to change this:

```
cpses = CanonPerson.objects.filter(persons__vpd = 1)
```

to this:

```
cpses = CanonPerson.objects.filter(persons__vpd in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

But this throws an exception:

```
NameError: global name 'persons__vpd' is not defined
```

**Models:**

```
class CanonPerson(models.Model):
    p_id                = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    persons             = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name='persons')

class Person(models.Model):
    vp_id               = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    p_id                = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    vpd                 = models.ForeignKey(VPD, db_column='vpd')

class VPD(models.Model):
    id          = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: it should probably be CanonPerson.objects.filter(persons__vpd__in = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

Comment: No, it says: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: How is your CanonPerson model ?

Comment: I think you better post your models and their relations, then we can post better guesses.

Comment: Alright, I have inserted the models. I hope this helps. Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks

Comment: With https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut , `CanonPerson.objects.filter(persons__vpd__in=[1,2,3,4,5])` should work...

Comment: Almost. CanonPerson.objects.filter(persons__vpd__id__in=[1,2,3,4,5])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut , `CanonPerson.objects.filter(persons__vpd__in=[1,2,3,4,5])` should work.

Comment: yeah. i suggested exact same thing in my first comment, but he replied that it generates an error. Because person.vpd is an object not number.  I'ts person.vpd.id which is in the list, so the persons__vpd__id__in should work.

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb I appologise, I believe I had overlooked the `__in` in your comment. Your initial comment was correct.